# What changes should I make to this code so it solves the system of linear equations?

Tags: c, loops, matrix, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,n;
    float A[20][20],c,x[10];
    scanf("%d",&n);//size of matrix
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
        {
            printf(" A[%d][%d]:", i,j);
            scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //looking for elements in the diagonal matrix
    for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
                for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
                {
                    A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        x[i]=A[i][n+1]/A[i][i];
        printf("\n x%d=%f\n",i,x[i]);//solution
    }
    return(0);
}
```

it prints things like "#IO". The algorithm is supposed to have three equations with n variables as inputs. I think the problem is when I divide by zero, but I don't know what can I add in order to avoid that.

Comment: looks okay: http://ideone.com/E9S8wK

Comment: Do a test on A[j][j] and A[i][i] to avoid the divide by 0.

Comment: You should post the whole message it prints.